# Do I need to use a pre-processed dataset to classify comments?

Tags: neural-networks, natural-language-processing, classification, tensorflow, data-preprocessing

I want to use Machine Learning for text classification, more precisely, I want to determine whether a text (or comment) is positive or negative. I can download a dataset with 120 million comments. I read the TensorFlow [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/basic_text_classification) and they also have a text dataset. This dataset is already pre-processed, like the words are converted to integers and the most used words are in the top 10000.

Do I also have to use a pre-processed dataset like them? If yes, does it have to be like the dataset from TensorFlow? And which pages could help me to implement that kind of program?

My steps would be:

1. find datasets
2. preprocess them if needed
3. feed them in the neural network

Answer (score 2):

Here's a list of some of the best python libraries for natural language processing.

- [Natural Language Toolkit (`nltk`)](https://www.nltk.org/)
  Covers all the basic functions and NLP tools such as tokenization etc.
- [TextBolb](https://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/dev/)
  This is a good library of beginners, it provides the `nltk` toolkit in a simplified format.
- [Spacy](https://spacy.io/)
  It is an advanced library and can be used in production code.

You can preprocess textual data in a number of ways. It depends on the type of task at hand and the size of the data.

From your question, I think you are referring to converting the words to a vector form `word2vec`. [Here](https://code.google.com/archive/p/word2vec/) is a massive word2vect list from Google.

Also have a look at preprocessing techniques in NLP such as `tf-idf` etc.